# can we create gif image without lzw compression?

Tags: compression, gif, lzw

I want to create a gif image from scratch using hex codes. I do not want to use LZW compression on the image data I produce. Is it possible to create a gif without LZW compression on image data so that all image viewing softwares can read it?

Comment: What makes you think that *any* image viewing software will have trouble when using a standard-compliant gif image? What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question with anything other than "Yes, just check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Uncompressed_GIF)". Do you have a specific question? Are you using a specific library? What language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no uncompressed option in the GIF format. The image data is always compressed with LZW.